# How to find if a string entered into scanner is in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner

I have to:

Prompt the user for a string,
if the string entered is in the array "names", print out its index,
if not in names, print out "NOT FOUND"

this is what I have:

This is for my programming final and i can't figure out how to do this because I missed 1 class...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Final1 {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      int y;
      int x=0;

      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

      String[] names = {"bob", "maxwell", "charley", "tomtomjack"};

      System.out.print("Enter String Name:");
         y=s.nextInt();

            for (String a: names){
               if (a.equals(y)) 
                  System.out.println(y);   
            }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you get user input as `int`.

User input values are `String` in order to check names since names are contained in a `String` array.

You can try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       String y;
      int x=0;
      int found = 0; //to identify the index 

      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

      String[] names = {"bob", "maxwell", "charley", "tomtomjack"};

      System.out.print("Enter String Name:");
         y=s.nextLine();

            for (String a: names){
               if (a.equals(y)) 
                { 
                    System.out.println("index of "+a+" is :"+x);   
                    found++; // increment if found 
                }
                
                x++;//iterate each time to get the index
            }
            
            if(found == 0)// check if it is not found
                 System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Enter String Name:charley
>
> index of charley is :2

Comment: Thank you Minoli, I have found this to be very helpful and now I understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: And now you've helped a [Help Vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire), and in doing so have encouraged them to further dump their assignments on this site.

Comment: @CaptainMuffenz welcome. but take some time and try to identify by yourself first. Then you can learn and remember these type of errors easily.

Comment: @Hovercraft agree.

Comment: @MinoliAlles I did try, for 2 days. Couldn't figure it out because of the class i missed. It basically had everything I needed to know how to do this project

Answer (score 3):

Use `Array.asList(yourArray).contains(yourValue)`:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Final1 
{

public static void main (String[] args) 
{
     int y = 0;
     int x = 0;
     String name = "";

     Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

     String[] names = {"bob", "maxwell", "charley", "tomtomjack"};

     System.out.print("Enter String Name:");

     name = s.nextLine();

     if(Arrays.asList(names).contains(name)) // Check this line
     {
        System.out.print(name);   
     }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to print the index of it instead of the actual name again you will have to modify it a bit.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Final1 
{

  public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
     int y = 0;
     int x = 0;
     String name = "";
     boolean found = false;

     Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

     String[] names = {"bob", "maxwell", "charley", "tomtomjack"};

     System.out.print("Enter String Name:");

     name = s.nextLine(); // get a string instead of an int

     // likely the way your professor would like you to do this
     // there are many ways, but this is the quickest while using a simple array
     // you could cast it to a list
     for(int i=0; i<names.length; ++i){
       if(names[i].equals(name)){
         System.out.print(i);
         found = true;
       }
     }

     if(!found)
       System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
  }
}
```

Edit: You could also use the Arrays static class.

```
int result = Arrays.binarySearch(names, name);
if(result > 0)
  System.out.println(result);
else
  System.out.println("NOT FOUND");
```

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing `int y` with scanned Integer. `y` should be a string and you should scan for a String.

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Final1 {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      int x=0;

      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

      String[] names = {"bob", "maxwell", "charley", "tomtomjack"};

      System.out.print("Enter String Name:");
         String y=s.nextLine();

            for (String a: names){
               if (a.equals(y)) 
                  System.out.println(y);   
            }

   }
}
```

Comment: We never even went over how to make scanner into a string in my class... RIP

Comment: And now you've helped a [Help Vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire), and in doing so have encouraged them to further dump their assignments on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Your `y` should be a `String` and you should input it with an `s.nextLine()`. Currently you are matching integers and strings. You could use the `indexOf`

```
int index = Arrays.asList(names).indexOf(s.nextLine());
return index > -1 ? "Not found" : Integer.toString(index);
```